# SQLite. Запрос на одну запись по ее ID

Tags: java, android, sql, sqlite

Как в android  выводить в `ListView` только одну строку из базы данных? Может запрос какой есть по _id или еще что-то?

Comment: Что именно у вас не получается. Составить запрос на языке SQL, получить эту строку по запросу, вывести полученную строку в список или еще что? Что вы уже пытались сделать и пример ваших неудачных попыток.

Comment: Я знаю как делать запрос к столбцу,  а как сделать запрос к строке?

Comment: То есть ваша проблема в том, что вы не можете составить запрос на получение всей строки по ID. Так и надо писать в вопросе. Чем он более полный, тем быстрее и качественнее вы модете получить решение.

Answer (score 2):

```
long id = 10;
Cursor cursor = db.query(("table name", null, "_id = ?", new String[] {Long.toString(id)}, null, null, null);
 // или упрощенная запись (не рекомендуется)
 // Cursor cursor = db.query(("table name", null, "_id = " + id, null, null, null, null);

cursor.moveToFirst();
```

курсор будет содержать все столбцы для строки в таблице *table name*, _id которой = 10 и указатель курсора будет спозиционирован на эту строку.

[Больше примеров](http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/76-urok-36-sqlite-podrobnee-pro-metod-query-uslovie-sortirovka-gruppirovka.html) по составлению запросов